# How to make time maximum validation with ozzo validation in golang

Tags: validation, go, backend

I want to make a maximum input for time with format time like (23:30:00) and the maximum time is (09:30:00), i tried the validation using ozzo validation and i find the function and its call "Date(layout string)"

It is the documentation https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation

From the documentation i see that the function Date has Min and Max to check specified range but the problem is i don't know how to fill the arguments. The data type is time.Time.

Here is my code

```
if err := validation.Validate(c.ReleasedTime, validation.Date("15:04:05").Max(????)); err != nil {
    logger.E(err)
    return shared.NewMultiStringValidationError(shared.HTTPErrorBadRequest, map[string]string{
        "en": "Format date",
        "id": "format tanggal",
    })
}
```

From there i fill the Max arguments "???" because i still confuse how to fill it.
Maybe you all can help me to find the this solution or make this validation using another package, i'll be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in the testing code.

You could see it here: https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/blob/master/date_test.go#L71

But when we only need compare hour, so it will be a little hack here.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    validation "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v4"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
    // this add a base date to hour, so we have a valid time.Time object.
    base := "2020-01-01"
    max, _ := time.Parse(layout, base+"T"+"23:30:00")
    fmt.Println(max)
    r := validation.Date(layout).Max(max)
    fmt.Println(r.Validate(base + "T" + "09:00:00")) // ok
    fmt.Println(r.Validate(base + "T" + "23:40:00")) // this should raise error
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, i appreciate it, but unfortunately it's doesn't work for my project, i have problem with format date that i use and finally i use my own validation
Maybe in another project i can use that hack, thanks for your answer